# Java Timer Scheduled Tasks Execution Speed

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

Suppose that I have the general scheduled task shown below
                Timer t = new Timer();

```
    TimerTask listenHandover = new TimerTask() {

    public void run() 
    {
              // Some methods that can possibly take more than 1 second to execute
    }
};
t.schedule(listenHandover, 1000 , 1000);
```

As the comment says, what happens if the task takes more than 1 second to execute ? Will the currentlly running one will be restarted when the next one is scheduled ? or do the tasks have their own threads ?  Hope it was clear. Thanks

Comment: Did you try and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If task takes more than 1 second, subsequent tasks will be queued up until offending one completes.

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

> If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.